# ¿Como Actualizar el tamaño del disco existente en Google Cloud Google Compute Engine en un Grupo de Instancias?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Necesito una Actualización del tamaño del disco persistente en Google Compute Engine con un Grupo de Instancias

¡no es posible porque la gestiona un grupo de instancias!

Comment: No entiendo estás preguntando o haciendo un aporte?

Comment: ¿Cuál se la pregunta? Ref. [ask].

Comment: Un aporte para una pregunta que no encontré

Comment: @JoseFernandezMarmolejo crear tus propios aportes es algo bienvenido en StackOverflow, pero deben seguir el formato Pregunta/Respuesta del sitio. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para hacerla una pregunta en sí, y pon la respuesta en la zona de respuestas. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: @JoseFernandezMarmolejo No voto en favor de que cierren tu publicación, debido a que creo que tiene potencial. Pero trata de mejorar la redacción tanto de tu pregunta como de tu respuesta. Revisé tu blog y te sugiero que, en lugar de usar este sitio como introductorio para tu blog, mejor uses SOes para explicar lo que hay en tu blog; ya dentro del contenido de tu publicación podrás hacer referencia a tu blog. Por otra parte, traté de editar tu respuesta para que pudiera ser leída con más fluidez, y con esto poder ampliar su alcance y mejorar la experiencia de quienes la lean.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez estés trabajando con un grupo de instancias de google cloud y necesites aumentar el tamaño del disco de tus instancias.

No se puede aumentar el tamaño del disco porque lo gestiona un grupo.

En este blog te voy a dar una forma de hacerlo sencillo y rápido, para comenzar adjunto un arquitectura utilizada donde me sucedió el error:
[image: Google Compute Engine Arquitectura web server]

La arquitectura es bastante sencilla. Tenemos la petición y la recibimos en nuestro DNS, en el record type A se tiene la dirección ip estatica del *frontend* y tiene un servicio de *backend* https que apunta al grupo de instancias creado a través de nuestra plantilla de instancias corriendo con Linux.

Todo marchaba bien hasta que disco se llenó, y posteriormente la instancia se cayó.

Cuando se intenta aumentar el disco del grupo de instancias, sale inhabilitado:

[image: No se puede aumentar el tamaño de discopersitente de google]

A la instancia en este caso no se le puede hacer nada porque la gestiona un grupo se soluciona con varios pasos que resumo:

https://josefernandezmarmolejo.blogspot.com/2020/11/actualizacion-del-tamano-del-disco.html